# How to know if an XML property was defined?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom TextView and I want to find out, in the constructor, if a certain XML property was declared, or not, in the corresponding xml layout.

```
<com.stuff.CustomTextView
  android:id="@+id/tv01"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="8sp" />

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
   // find out if textSize was defined
   if (!wasAttributeDefined(attrs,"textSize")) // EDIT
     setTextSize(10); // EDIT
}
```

I don't know if this is valid, but I tried the following (without luck):

```
attrs.getAttributeFloatValue("android","textSize",(float)-1.0);
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

well, if anyone is interested, there is a (probably not so good) way of solving this. someting like:

```
private boolean wasAttributeDefined(AttributeSet attrs, String name) {
    for (int i=0; i<attrs.getAttributeCount(); i++)
        if (attrs.getAttributeName(i).equals(name))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you placed your log? Getting any error?

Comment: no errors. just getting the default value I provided (-1.0), in spite of having defined android:textSize in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You should test your attribute using something like:

`R.id.tv01.attr.textSize`

Comment: This will give you the value set in the attribute android:textSize of the widget with the id tv01

Comment: the thing is, I want to know if the property was declared (in the XML) every time a "new" CustomTextView comes up, in the constructor, not for a single/specific one.